# IP address and staying anonymous?

Tags: anonymity, security, onion-routing, ip-address

What identification information does Tor strip besides IP addresses? I realize that, by filtering through ORs, my IP address is no longer identifiable. But what other ID information, besides the data itself (eg an email in which I write my address), can be found if not for Tor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tor strips (or really just discards) all network level information up to (and excluding) the application [Application Layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer).

Anything sent on the application layer is transmitted as-is and Tor takes no steps to modify or alter the Application Layer data in any way, including any identifying information.

Comment: Thanks for answering, cannonizing ironize, but what specific identifying information is generally stored in those discarded layers, besides IP addresses?